# Convert .fon to TTF or OTF

Tags: windows, windows-xp, fonts, conversion

How can I convert a bitmap fonts (.fon) into TTF or OTF fonts?

I don't need any of the features in vector fonts such as ClearType; I just want my bitmap font simply transformed into TTF or OTF format.

Comment: You can’t. TTF and OTF are vector formats — such things need to be done by hand.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750124/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-font-fon-into-a-truetype-font-ttf

Answer (score 2):

Most typography software can do font format conversion. [TransType](http://www.fontlab.com/font-converter/transtype/) and [KGroup PixelFont](http://www.kgroup.ru/products.html) are example of commercial applications. If you want free solutions, you can use [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) + [Autotrace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autotrace/files/AutoTrace/) (FontForge needs Autotrace for tracing).